# Writing device drivers for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, driver

I have a high level question I seek information on:

Is it possible to write a device driver in iOS ? Is it possible to write a driver & deploy it to my iPhone or iPad ?

If yes, then are the drivers advised to be written in language Swift ? Or is c ?

Comment: what exactly do you consider *drivers* in your case?

Comment: drivers? for what? what is your idea?

Comment: I meant device drivers. but from the answers, it looks like not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, no.

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, so more details may be helpful, but by the sound of it, no you can't write and deploy device drivers on iOS.

iOS is tightly locked down by Apple. Each app lives in its own [sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/) in an effort to keep the system secure. You have access to the public APIs. Accessing private APIs may result in your app being rejected from the [review process](https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/app-store/review/guidelines/App-Review-Guidelines-The-Comic-Book.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

In order to write and install device drivers for iOS devices you would need to get support from Apple. There are various types of drivers depending on what it is you want to do. They have a program for vendors who make accessories that plug into the lightning port (or the older 30-pin port) and another program for manufacturers of Bluetooth devices. Both require licenses from Apple.

I'm not sure what other types of device drivers are possible. You need to be more specific.

Comment: The program you are talking about is mfi I guess
https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/
Looks like we get access to private APIs once enrolled in the mfi.

Comment: Your question is too vague to be useful on this site, or answerable. You  need to add more detail to your question.